# Making NSManagedObject Codable and Store Image Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, image-processing, core-data

I am working on an App with offline capabilities. I have to fetch the JSON data from the network and store it in Core Data. Rest of the data is pretty straight forward, but I am wondering what's the best way to handle the image. JSON response gives the URL and then I have to download the image and store the data of the image into Core Data. I am making NSManagedObject Codable, so I can capture that URL. I am having the extra optional variable 
`albumImage` with data. Is this the right approach? I would use `albumArtwork` to store the URL, I would use that URL to download the image and store the data into `albumImage`. The sole purpose of `albumImage` being in this model is to store image data and not handle the JSON response. I just want to know if there is any better way of handling this.

**JSON:**

```
{
                "artistName": "Ozuna",
                "id": "1433976640",
                "releaseDate": "2018-08-24",
                "name": "Aura",
                "kind": "album",
                "copyright": "℗ 2018 VP Records Corp./Dimelo Vi Dist. by Sony Music Entertainment U.S. Latin LLC",
                "artistId": "283578837",
                "artistUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/ozuna/283578837?app=music",
                "artworkUrl100": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music128/v4/d7/60/f7/d760f7bf-e2bc-e48e-afcd-b9b562ad4c2f/697691884080.jpg/200x200bb.png"
}
```

**Model to handle the JSON Response:**

```
public class Album: NSManagedObject, Codable {
    @NSManaged public var artistName: String
    @NSManaged public var albumName: String
    @NSManaged public var copyrightInfo: String
    @NSManaged public var albumArtwork: String
    @NSManaged public var albumReleaseDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var linkToAppStore: String
    @NSManaged public var albumImage: NSData?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bothering yourself of storing the data of the image , I recommend to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and store only the url in CoreData as **URI**

```
import SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with:url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

to make use of the download & cache

Comment: In that case, how would I get the offline access? I believe if I store URL in Core Data and if there is no network connectivity, I won't be able to use SDWebImage. Right? I want to store images for offline usage.

Comment: @VandanPatel , if the image is cached in sdwebimage , then it will be shown in offline mode

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons with storing data blobs in CoreData vs on the disk as seperate files. Storing in files means you have to keep track of them and clean up properly when they are deleted or changed which is a bit of a pain.

In your case I would just store the data directly in CoreData, however use a seperate CoreData object (eg AlbumImage), that has a 1-to-1 relationship with the Album object. This keep things fast when you are just working with Album objects and don't want the image data loaded into memory.

CoreData also has the 'allows external storage' option which will actually store the data as a file on disk anyway (once a certain size threshold is met) so you can try that too.

-

Regarding your comments.

If you have a `AlbumVC` listing Albums where you can sort/search/filter then it would be unnecessarily using a lot of ram to have all the full sized image data sitting in memory. If you have a secondary object then it only needs to load into memory when the user drills down into `AlbumDetailVC`.

You can still keep the same interface to access the image, just have that method call the child object. Something like this.

```
- (UIImage *)image
{
    return [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData.data];
}
```

Comment: Those are all really good points. Just one follow up question though. I think I would want to associate image data with every Album object. That's why I have albumImage as part of Album object. Would it be possible for you to give me an example or use case where it would be beneficial to have it in a separate entity?