# How to cache the images offline in swift(without internet connection)?

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoa-touch, core-data, firebase-storage

I am able to fetch the images and cache it when user has internet connection. But how to cache the image offline(when user has no internet connection, try to open the app). Below is my code

```
func downloadImages(){
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()



        for i in animated_images{
            let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(i).jpg")
            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                else{
                    self.downloaded_images.updateValue(url!, forKey: i)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! demoCell
        cell.textDemo.text = images[indexPath.row]

        var image1 = downloaded_images[images[indexPath.row]]
        var image2 = downloaded_images[images[indexPath.row]+"1"]

        var value1 = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromCache(forKey: image1?.absoluteString)
        var value2 = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromCache(forKey: image2?.absoluteString)

        if let downloadURL1 = value1, let downloadURL2 = value2{
            cell.imageDemo.animationImages = [downloadURL1,downloadURL2]
            cell.imageDemo.animationDuration = 2
            cell.imageDemo.startAnimating()
        }
        else{
            cell.imageDemo.sd_setAnimationImages(with: [image1!,image2!])
            cell.imageDemo.animationDuration = 2
            cell.imageDemo.startAnimating()
        }

        return cell
    }
```

I am New to iOS development and I have some idea on Coredata and sqlite. Please guide me how to do it without internet connection. Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, you don't appear to be using Core Data.  So you first need to decide whether or not you are using Core Data.  That's why Xcode asks you during File > New Project.  If you do want to use Core Data, you will rewrite some of the above code, and the answer *how to cache images offline* can be found in various questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285091/making-nsmanagedobject-codable-and-store-image-data/52286853#52286853)

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the images in my App without Internet Connection , I created a table named cached_image with fields image_name and download_url and saved the respective urls for the images. When the app gets loaded those cached_images details fetched from the local sqlite db and Images are displayed